# Код не выводит текст из txt. В чем проблеиа?

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
$filename = get_file_content(C:\Users\User\Desktop\fff\tut.txt);
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
echo $contents;
?>
```

Comment: `echo file_get_contents("C:\Users\User\Desktop\fff\tut.txt");`

Comment: Все равно пустой экран, может проблема в вордпресс?

Comment: Смотрите логи, ищите там ошибки

Comment: @ArchDemon `echo "C:\Users\User\Desktop\fff\tut.txt";`

Comment: @Ипатьев, думаю, у автора и такой бы код не заработал

Comment: к сожаленью, вы правы

Comment: @ArchDemon так он и не заработал, тут и думать не надо. потому что твой код нерабочий

Comment: Где еще может быть ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

Вы экранируете символы в строке:

```
echo "C:\Users\User\Desktop\fff\tut.txt";
```

выведет «C:\Users\User\Desktopff ut.txt»

Замените двойные кавычки на одинарные:

```
$filename = file_get_contents('C:\Users\User\Desktop\fff\tut.txt');
```

[Прочитать про экранирование можно здесь](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php)

Кроме того, у вас вместо правильной `file_get_contents` написано `get_file_content`. Включите вывод ошибок — php будет ругаться на несуществующие функции.