# Почему код не выводит на страницу информацию из txt

Tags: php, html

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>д</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <?php
    file_get_contents = 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\fff\tut.txt';
    ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Код не выводит текст из txt. В чем проблеиа?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1221087/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%b7-txt-%d0%92-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b8%d0%b0)

Answer (score 6):

```
echo file_get_contents('C:\Users\User\Desktop\fff\tut.txt');
```

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php
Было бы не плохо ознакомиться с документацией по этой функции и языке в общем